# SAS: Using WHERE / IF Statement in SGPlot

Tags: syntax, sas, data-analysis

Good afternoon,

I would like to define my parameters in my plot as opposed to generating a plot with all values.

For example, I want to show only the sale price of the data not exceeding $400,000. This syntax is not correct, but this is my attempt at it. Should I use the if, by, or where statement in this matter? Thank you!

```
proc sgplot data=mydata; 
loess x = FirstFlrSF  y = saleprice / group= OverallQual;
reg x = FirstFlrSF y = saleprice;
where saleprice =< 400000;
title "First Floor SF vs sales price"; run;
```

Comment: WHERE can usually go anywhere in a proc. But you have your comparison operator specified incorrectly, <=

Comment: I corrected my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IF's don't work in PROCS, but WHERE's do, however you have the comparison operator specified incorrectly. It's `<=` instead of `=<`. I always remember the order by saying it out loud, less than or equal to.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
scatter x=height y=weight;
where age <= 15;
run;quit;
```

Answer (score -1):

The placement of the where statement was not in the correct line.

```
proc sgplot data=mydata (where =(saleprice <= 400000)); 
loess x = FirstFlrSF  y = saleprice / group= OverallQual;
reg x = FirstFlrSF y = saleprice;
title "First Floor SF vs sales price"; run;
```